# how to count click and show with Toast

Tags: android, android-toast

I need to count clicks on a button and show on a TOAST, when i try the android VM take a loop

```
 final Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int contadorClicks =0;
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //definir accion

            contadorClicks ++ ;

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contadorClicks, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does "take a loop" mean?

Comment: Use `String.valueOf(contadorClicks)` as second parameter in makeText method

Comment: try `static int contadorClicks`

Comment: you need to learn java

Answer (score 0):

try: 
   create int contadorClicks =0; field in class i.e activity or fragment
   then inside method use

```
 final Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //definir accion
        contadorClicks ++ ;
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(contadorClicks), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

or you can do something like:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //definir accion
            Integer contadorClicks;
            if (v.getTag() == null) {
                contadorClicks = 0;
            } else {
                contadorClicks = (Integer) v.getTag();
            }
            contadorClicks++;
            v.setTag(contadorClicks);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(contadorClicks), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the variable which you're going to increment outside of the setOnClickListener method. Also, as suggested before me, use String.valueOf(contadorClicks) to get a String represantation of the int.

```
int contadorClicks = 0;    

final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        //definir accion

        contadorClicks++;

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(contadorClicks), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your variable contadorClicks always is gonna be 0 because it's being created each time you click the button. What you need to do is put that variable outside the onClickListener. Hope this helps

```
int contadorClicks = 0;
final Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //definir accion

            contadorClicks ++ ;

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contadorClicks, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```